# Recursion on select

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have two select controls and on select I want to repopulate both select controls with new data. For example if I select one option it will call relevant subscribe function, then the new data will be passed in to "refresh" function and here it sets the new data to both selection controls, but also at this moment I get a recursion problem, which calls subscribe function again and so on, so basically I don't have any idea on how to fix this recursive call.

**jsFiddle** example:

http://jsfiddle.net/fWTpE/

**HTML**:

```
<select class="select"  data-bind="value: currentSourceOne, options: sourceOne, optionsValue: function(item) { return item; }, optionsText: function(item) { return item.text; }, optionsCaption: &#39;Select&#39;"></select>

<select class="select"  data-bind="value: currentSourceTwo, options: sourceTwo, optionsValue: function(item) { return item; }, optionsText: function(item) { return item.text; }, optionsCaption: &#39;Select&#39;"></select>
```

**JS**:

```
function ViewModel(data) {

            var self = this;

            self.refresh = function (data) {

                if (data.currentObject != null) {

                    self.sourceOne(data.currentObject.sourceOne);
                }
            };

            self.currentObject = ko.observable(data.currentObject);

            self.sourceOne = ko.observableArray(self.currentObject().sourceOne);
            self.currentSourceOne.subscribe(function(value) {

                if(value) {

                    // omitted the code which generates new data

                    self.refresh(data);
                }
            });

            // omitted repetitive code for second select control
        };

        $(function () {

            // omitted the code which generates data

            ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(data));
        });
```

Comment: What is the "recursion problem"? Describe it in detail and paste only the code that is relevant with the problem.

Comment: I am sorry, I just updated the description and code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a mark variable to break the recursion. If the recursion is synchronous, it can be done like the following:

```js
function ViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.refresh = function (data) {
        if (data.currentObject != null) {
            self.sourceOne(data.currentObject.sourceOne);
        }
    };

    self.currentObject = ko.observable(data.currentObject);
    self.sourceOne = ko.observableArray(self.currentObject().sourceOne);
    // initialize a mark at outer scope
    var isSubscribing = false;
    self.currentSourceOne.subscribe(function (value) {
        // we are in a recursion, break out
        if (isSubscribing)
            return;
        // begin subscribing, set the mark
        isSubscribing = true;
        if (value) {
            // omitted the code which generates new data
            self.refresh(data);
        }
        // finished subscribing, restore mark
        isSubscribing = false;
    });
    // omitted repetitive code for second select control
};

$(function () {
    // omitted the code which generates data
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(data));
});
```

However, if the subscribe-refresh-subscribe-... recursion is asynchronous, you'll have to figure out where is the actual terminate point of a **subscribe-refresh** pair and put the restore mark code `isSubscribing = false;` at the end of that point.